# sql - Selecting row that compares against values in other rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

My database looks something like this

```
Value | Date     | parent_id
 y    | 2019-01-01 | 1
 n    | 2019-01-02 | 1
 n    | 2019-01-03 | 1
```

I want to write a query that will look for a row that has `parent_id = 1` and `value = 'y'`, and also evaluate it against other rows that have `parent_id=1'` but will check to make sure the `date` is greater than its row's date.

So in this case it won't return anything.

If the data was like:

```
Value | Date     | parent_id
 y    | 2019-01-04 | 1
 n    | 2019-01-02 | 1
 n    | 2019-01-03 | 1
```

Then it would return the first row.

If it means anything, I am using SQLite.

Comment: This is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NOT EXISTS:

```
select * from tablename t
where 
  parent_id = 1 and value = 'y'
  and not exists (
    select 1 from tablename 
    where parent_id = t.parent_id
    and date > t.date
  )
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sUuuQPaNmC4oxVw9vQTXve/1).
As a suggestion: since you are using **SQLite**,you should consider to change the format of the `Date` column to `YYYY-MM-DD`, so that it is comparable.

Comment: It is SQLite on a PC, right? Don't expect miracles.

Comment: yea, I think its more my computer than the query...it says the query only takes a second but my computer locks up hah...I've heard that subqueries are really slow, is that true?

Comment: Every subquery running over and over for each row of a table is slow. But this depends on your actual data and the filters and your needs. In your case the 1st 2 conditions `parent_id = 1 and value = 'y'` should minimize the need to run the subquery for every row.

Answer (score 1):

With SQLite >= 3.25, simply use [window function `ROW_NUMBER()`](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html#built_in_window_functions) :

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.parent_id ORDER BY t.date DESC) rn
    FROM mytable t
) x WHERE rn = 1 AND parent_id = 1 AND value = 'y'
```

Window function are usually more efficient than correlated subqueries.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wB65KbxuTPAM8KKWgRKezg/0)**.

---

The query works as follows.

First, it traverses the table and uses `ROW_NUMBER()` to assign a a rank to each record within the group of records having the same `parent_id`, and with the record with the highest `date` numbered `1`. You can run the subquery to see what it actually returns (it gets more interesting when there is more than one `parent_id`) :

```
SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.parent_id ORDER BY t.date DESC) rn
FROM mytable t
```

Then, all that is left to do to is filter on the target `parent_id`, pick the record with row number 1 (ie the record that has the highest `date` for this `parent_id`), and make sure that it has `value = 'y'`.

Comment: while this might be right...im new to sql and this is super confusing sorry :(

Comment: @MorganAllen : well, we are all here to learn... I updated my answer with more details !

Comment: that's super helpful! I'll definitely play around and experiment with some of those more advanced features :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another method just looks for the last row to see if it meets your conditions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
      from t
      where t.parent_id = 1
      order by t.date desc
      limit 1
     ) t
where value = 'y';
```

This checks that the last row with `parent_id = 1` has the value of `'y'`.